# How can I combine multiple text files, remove duplicate lines and split the remaining lines into several files of certain length?

Tags: list, split, duplicates, notepad++, bigdata

I have a lot of relatively small files with about 350.000 lines of text.
For example:

File 1:

```
 asdf
 wetwert
 ddghr
 vbnd
 ...
 sdfre
```

File 2:

```
 erye
 yren
 asdf
 jkdt
 ...
 uory
```

As you can see line 3 of file 2 is a duplicate of line 1 in file 1.
I want a program / Notepad++ Plugin that can check and remove these duplicates in multiple files.

The next problem I have is that I want all lists to be combined into large 1.000.000 line files.
So, for example, I have these files:

- 648563 lines
- 375924 lines
- 487036 lines

I want them to result in these files:

- 1.000.000 lines
- 511.523 lines

And the last 2 files must consist of only unique lines.
How can I possibly do this? Can I use some programs for this? Or a combination of multiple Notepad++ Plugins?
I know GSplit can split files of 1.536.243 into files of 1.000.000 and 536.243 lines, but that is not enough, and it doesn't remove duplicates.

I do want to create my own Notepad++ plugin or program if needed, but I have no idea how and where to start.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Are the line numbers actually part of the files? If yes, they need to be ignored for duplicate checking, right? Do they need to be preserved in the output? Must the order of the lines be preserved?

Comment: @Pharaoh No the line numbers are not part of the file, and the order of the lines doesn't matter.

Comment: Do you want to remove ALL duplicates or keep one of them?

Comment: @Toto I want to keep one of them, so basically, I want to keep only unique lines.

Comment: Then @Pharaoh answer should work for you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have asked about Notepad++ and are thus using Windows. On the other hand, you said you want to create a program if needed, so I guess the main goal is to get the job done.
This answer uses Unix tools - on Windows, you can get those with [Cygwin](https://cygwin.com/).

To run the commands, you have to type (or paste) them in the terminal / console.

```
cat file1 file2 file3 | sort -u | split -l1000000 - outfile_
```

`cat` reads the files and echoes them; normally, to the screen, but the pipe `|` gets the output of the command left to it and pipes it through to the command on the right.

`sort` obviously sorts them, and the switch `-u` tells it to remove duplicate lines.

The output is then piped to `split` which is being told to split after 1000000 lines by the switch `-l1000000`. The `-` (with spaces around) tells it to read its input not from a file but from "standard input"; the output in `sort -u` in this case. The last word, `outfile_`, can be changed by you, if you want.

Written like it is, this will result in files like `outfile_aa`, `outfile_ab` and so on - you can modify this with the last word in this command.

If you have all the files in on directory, and nothing else is in there, you can use `*` instead of listing all the files:

```
cat * | sort -u | split -l1000000 - outfile_
```

If the files might contain empty lines, you might want to remove them. Otherwise, they'll be sorted to the top and your first file will not have the full 1.000.000 values:

```
cat file1 file2 file3 | grep -v '^\s*$' | sort -u | split -l1000000 - outfile_
```

This will also remove lines that consist only of whitespace.
`grep` filters input using regular expressions. `-v` inverts the filter; normally, `grep` keeps only lines that match. Now, it keeps only lines that don't match. `^\s*$` matches all lines that consist of nothing else than 0 or more characters of whitespace (like spaces or tabs).

If you need to do this regularly, you can write a script so you don't have to remember the details:

```
#!/bin/sh
cat * | sort -u | split -l1000000 - outfile_
```

Save this as a file (for example `combine.sh`) and run it with

```
./combine.sh
```